# Jquery Table Filter Modification

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have been using the following Jquery Table filter code below which works exactly as I needed it to. Now I need to add two more options that I dont know how to do. The filter is only filtering in a table column named "Materials Ordered". If it finds the exact text in the id="", that is the table rows that are shown.

What I need added to it is the following, still only looking in the same column:

1)      Add new filter option called “Open” which should:
-        Show all records except the records where all 4 products (Backsplash, Carpet, Tile & Wood) have either N/A or order date after it

2)      Add new filter option called “Closed” which should show:
-        Only show records where all 4 products (Backsplash, Carpet, Tile & Wood) have either N/A or order date after it

```
<input type="radio" id="" name="Materials Ordered" /> All
<input type="radio" id="Tile NOT" name="Materials Ordered" checked="checked">Tile
<input type="radio" id="Carpet NOT" name="Materials Ordered" /> Carpet
<input type="radio" id="Wood NOT" name="Materials Ordered" /> Wood
<input type="radio" id="Backsplash NOT" name="Materials Ordered" /> Backsplash
```

Here is a fiddle to the current filtering: https://jsfiddle.net/aL6141dq/

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {

$('input[type="radio"]').change(function () {
var name = $('input[name="name"]:checked').prop('id') || '';
var position = $('input[name="Materials Ordered"]:checked').prop('id') || '';
$('tbody tr').hide();
$('tbody tr:contains(' + name + ')').show();
$('tbody tr').not(':contains(' + position + ')').hide();
});

});
</script>
```

This is the jist of the second option:

```
(if Backspash tabletext = "Backspash mm/dd/yyyy" OR "Backspash N/A"
AND
if Carpet tabletext = "Carpet mm/dd/yyyy" OR "Carpet N/A"
AND
if Tile tabletext = "Tile mm/dd/yyyy" OR "Tile N/A"
AND
if Wood tabletext = "Wood mm/dd/yyyy" OR "Wood N/A")
{
SHOW Table Row)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, I haven't tested this, but it seems that you could do something like the following:

```
$('tbody tr').filter(function() {
  var matches = $(this).find('td').filter(function() {
    var val = $(this).text(),
        prefix = this.id.substring(0, this.id.length - 4) + ' ',
        datePattern = /^(\d{1,2})(\/|-)(\d{1,2})(\/|-)(\d{4})$/,
        suffix;

    if (val.substring(0, prefix.length) === prefix) {
        suffix = val.substring(prefix.length);
        if (suffix === 'N/A' || suffix.match(datePattern)) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
  }).length;

  return option === 'Closed' ? matches === 4 : matches !== 4;
}).show();
```

The idea is to look at the table cells in each row, filtering those that meet the criteria, and then count the results. The code extracts the beginning of valid values (e.g. 'Tile') by stripping the trailing ' NOT' from the ID. It then tests the remaining characters to see if they are 'N/A' or a date(clearly there could be more extensive date checking).

The number of matching cells in a row can then be checked to see which of the conditions are true and `show()` them accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

I have the answer now.

```
<input checked="checked" id="" name="Materials Ordered" type="radio"> All
<input id="openOrders" name="Materials Ordered" type="radio"> Open
<input id="closedOrders" name="Materials Ordered" type="radio"> Closed
<input id="Tile NOT" name="Materials Ordered" type="radio"> Tile
<input id="Carpet NOT" name="Materials Ordered" type="radio"> Carpet
<input id="Wood NOT" name="Materials Ordered" type="radio"> Wood
<input id="Backsplash NOT" name="Materials Ordered" type="radio"> Backsplash

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
$('input[type="radio"]').change(function() {
    $('tbody tr').show();
    var position = $('input[name="Materials Ordered"]:checked').prop('id') || '';
    if (position === 'openOrders') {
        $('tbody tr').not(':contains("NOT")').hide();
    } else if (position === 'closedOrders') {
        $('tbody tr:contains("NOT")').hide();
    } else {
        $('tbody tr').not(':contains(' + position + ')').hide();
    }
});
});
</script>
```